# Google Sheets - Seperate names by ", " and copy everything else in row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet that has various information about a behavior incident. When the row is populated, the person completing the form has the option to select multiple names from a database. This is inputted into the cell (Column E) like this ("John Doe, Bob Smith, Alex Dimple"). On a separate sheet I have a script running to copy the entire contents from the row, and create a separate row with each student. This is needed so that we can send out emails and use each row separately for our records. The script works most of the time, but it does stop working probably 1 a month. Sometimes it fixes itself and sometimes I have to go in there and recreate the sheet in order for it to work. I am looking for a more stable option. Here is the code below:

```
function name(range) {
var output2 = [];
for(var i=0, iLen=range.length; i<iLen; i++) {
var s = range[i][4].split(", ");    
for(var j=0, jLen=s.length; j<jLen; j++) {
  var output1 = []; 
  for(var k=0, kLen=range[0].length; k<kLen; k++) {
    if(k == 4) {
      output1.push(s[j]);
    } else {
      output1.push(range[i][k]);
    }
  }
  output2.push(output1);
}    
}
return output2;
}
```

This is the error I get when something goes wrong:
[Google Sheets Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySPZ9.png)

Comment: Try to log range before for loop.  And see what's your range bring to this function.   Error can be seen then.

Comment: I apologize, I do not know how to log range before the loop. Can you help with that?

Comment: You should share some more details, like how tables are looking in sheet, and still can't understand what you're trying to achieve, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this and look at your execution logs for errors and information about the range contents for that error

```
function name(range) {
  if (range) {
    var output2 = [];
    for (var i = 0, iLen = range.length; i < iLen; i++) {
      var s = range[i][4].split(", ");
      for (var j = 0, jLen = s.length; j < jLen; j++) {
        var output1 = [];
        for (var k = 0, kLen = range[0].length; k < kLen; k++) {
          if (k == 4) {
            output1.push(s[j]);
          } else {
            output1.push(range[i][k]);
          }
        }
        output2.push(output1);
      }
    }
    return output2;
  } else {
    throw "Error: parameter range is undefind";
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(range));
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I am getting in the execution log. In the cell it says "loading..." but it never loads.         5:37:01 PM Notice Execution started
5:37:01 PM Error 
Error: parameter range is undefind
name @ Name.gs:20

Comment: Oh this is a custom function.  I didn't realize that.   There is a problem with this that came up recent here is the link [issues](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/222342097)  This may be the issue you are having.